# NiMH battery charger of hair trimmer

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, charger

[image]Can you please help me to understand the working principle of this circuit. It's a simple circuit for charging the NiMH 1.2 V battery and driving the DC motor of a hair trimmer.

I'm confused because the rectifying diode is placed before the transformer. The transformer wiring is strange too.
I sent a new image of the same circuit the problem is with what I called tapped transformer in the image I think it's not transformer please help me
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please rotate your image.

Comment: I rotated it..thanks in advance

Comment: Rectifying before the transformer, and then chopping the current at a very high frequency with a transistor, is a common method of making a power supply smaller and cheaper. Mains-frequency transformers are large, but high-frequency ones can be much smaller.

Comment: From the schematic, that looks *deadly*! The line is connected to the output, with bare electrodes for contacts. Bad news anywhere, and in a device for use in the bathroom, downright homicidal.

Comment: Hearth thanks for your reply...I searched the internet and find something about that but this circuit still doesn't make sense to me I found it different from any other circuit like smps for example

Comment: I found something about flyback transformers but it's different here